# Enable php_exec function through .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I need to enable php_exec function which is in php.ini file.
Since, I am using shared hosting, I do not have access to php.ini file. How can i enable the same function through .htaccess file?

Please provide the syntax.

Many Thanks in Advance.

FYR : `exec() has been disabled for security reasons`

Regards,
Natu

Comment: Generaly shared hosts do not allow exec() as it would cause vulnerabilities

Comment: What is your provider ?

Comment: Some hosts will do this for you upon request. Maybe contact their support team first?

Comment: Some hosts will allow to activate this kind of functions (more likely within your allowed path) by using their backend interface / manager. It will be hard to tell you whether it is possible or not without knowing your host

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I am using netegrity hosting provider .i will contact to netegrity support team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply can't allow `exec` (and other similar functions disabled by php.ini) through .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can test it. put in your `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_php4.c> 
php_admin_value disable_functions "exec"
</IfModule>
```